# Network days function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I want to use the `NETWORKDAYS` function on a table in another sheet.

This is the formula I am using. `Details` is the table name

`=NETWORKDAYS(Details[Date1],Details[Date2])`

The formula is returning a `#Value!` error.

How can I use a table name in the `NETWORKDAYS` function?

[image]

Comment: As it's written you're evaluating 2 arrays of data. Try to put the formula in a separate column in the table only referencing the cells in that row. Then you can take the sum of that column if you need the total net workday difference.

Comment: @MarkS. turns out the issue wasn't that OP was *"evaluating 2 arrays"* but rather that she *wasn't*.  Turns out that NETWORKDAYS supports arrays but not ranges.  I didn't know that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Source Data: Range vs Array

According to [barry houdini's accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/609197/) to this [question](https://superuser.com/q/609193/) , the [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) function accepts `arrays` as arguments, but not `ranges`.  I have tested and confirmed this to be the case.

This explains why your formula is failing as you are you trying to pass in two ranges: `Details[Date1]` and `Details[Date2]`.  If you first convert the two ranges to arrays, [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) will successfully output an array of values.

It is simple enough to convert the ranges to arrays by adding zero to each range, or multiplying or dividing the ranges by one:   **`+0`** , **`*1`** , *or* **`/1`**

#### New Formula

```
=NETWORKDAYS(Details[Date1]+0,Details[Date2]+0)
```

<sub>**Formula Example**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Testing arguments containing Ranges vs. Arrays**</sub>
[image]

#### Note About Blank Cells

1. In the formulas above, blank cells are interpreted as zero
2. [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) will interpret zero as the numeric equivalent of `1/0/1900`
3. The numeric equivalent of a date `d` can be determined by counting the number of days between `d` and `1/0/1900` which is the equivalent of `VALUE(d)`
4. As a result, [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) will return `0` if both the argument cells are blank, and will still return a number if one of the cells is blank (positive or negative depending on which argument is zero).

###### Workaround

The workaround is to coerce zero values (blank cells) to an error

1. [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) will return an error if either argument provided to it is an error
2. Dividing one by the inverse of a number `n` will return `n` where `n<>0` but if `n=0` it will trigger an error: `1/(1/3)=3` but `1/(1/0)=#DIV/0!`
3. IFERROR will pass non-errors, but allow a different result if it detects an error.  In the formula below the alternative result is blank, `""`, but it could easily be `"Argument(s) Missing"`

###### Formula with Workaround

```
=IFERROR(NETWORKDAYS(1/(1/Details[Date1]),1/(1/Details[Date2])),"")
```

###### Multi-Line Version

```
=IFERROR(
  NETWORKDAYS(
    1/(1/Details[Date1]),
    1/(1/Details[Date2])),"")
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explaining in detail with all the screen shots. I really appreciate your time. You are an amazing person.

Comment: Np.  you were very responsive to my questions.  I wish it were that easy all the time.

Comment: Hi @Blind Spots, in your screenshot: "testing arguments containing ranges vs arrays", I am using the second formula. Small update on that, can you please tell me how do I update the formula if any one of the date argument or both date arguments are blank, I should get the results as blank( not as text 'blank: but just have to result as no data ).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I tried this formula and it worked as expected!!! Thank you so much! Thank you for explaining in detail, this makes it so easy to understand and use it. If I have any other questions about other formulas, how do I reach out you ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474461/how-to-write-multiple-if-conditions-when-referring-to-a-table-in-excel @Blind Spots can you please answer this question?

Comment: the question is deleted

Comment: It is important that you actually post the questions properly so that the next "Maddy" finds the answer when they are searching.  I am happy to answer any question you post if 
 I can.  [Stack Overflow SE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is really about programming questions.  You should probably post your non-programming Excel questions on [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), or if they are about the online version of Excel they may be okay on [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  I am on both.

Comment: IF(And(IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])-
1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")>0,
IFERROR(1/(1/Details[Date1])-
1/(1/Details[Date2]),"")<1), "metrics met"),
IF(IFERROR(1(1/Details[Date1])-
1(1/Details[Date2]),"")>1, "metrics not met") small update. posting my question here. How do I write the AND operator when there are multiple IF conditions.Please let me know

Comment: per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327285/network-days-function-in-excel/76327422?noredirect=1#comment134843375_76327422), please post at [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), I'll answer immediately.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1789071/how-to-use-and-operator-when-there-are-multiple-if-conditions-referring-a-table

Comment: I posted the link in the above comment. I hope you understood the question @Blind Spots